# How can I get into the large area in the bottom-right of the Sundari Flatlands?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I've been eyeing this area on the map (Republic only):

[image: map]

How can I get up there?  What's in that area?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Start off here — (1495, 1359) near the Upper Sundari Outpost:

[image]

After jumping up the rocks you'll get to this grassy plateau:

[image]

At the back of which is a path:

[image]

Head down here:

[image]

Hang a right:

[image]

You've made it!  This place is **entirely empty**, panorama:

[image: panorama]

But there are some invisible walls/floors:

[image]
[image]

This is overlooking where you head up:

[image]

It's hard (though not impossible) to get back out the way you came, but there's plenty of other ways out like just jumping down in the image above.  I was hoping for a datacron or something here (why else would I spend so much time trying to get up there :P), but nope.  Maybe something is planned for here in a future update.